# Why do I get bad output when using Nokogiri "search"?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I want to scrape data from specific divs on a CarFax report. However, when I search for divs, I always get this weird garbage output.

I tried `search(#divId)` , `search(.divClass)`, and even tried to grab all divs with `search('div')`. Each time I get similar results: the div's content is partially truncated and the tags are all messed up.

This is the URL I am loading into my `agent`: https://gist.github.com/atkolkma/8024287

This is the code (user and pass ommited):

```
require "rubygems"
require "mechanize"

scraper = Mechanize.new
scraper.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
scraper.follow_meta_refresh = true
scraper.redirect_ok = true

scraper.get("http://www.carfaxonline.com")
form = scraper.page.forms.first
form.j_username = "******"
form.j_password = "*****"
scraper.submit(form)

scraper.get("http://www.carfaxonline.com/api/report?vin=1G1AT58H697144202&track=true")

puts scraper.page.search("#headerBodyType")
```

This is what the file returns when I run it:

```
</div>4 DRderBodyType">
```

What I expect is:

```
<div id="headerBodyType"> SEDAN 4 DR </div>
```

The strangest thing is, if I copy the HTML source, save it as a new file, upload it and `search` it, I get the correct output! I've uploaded the copied HTML to my chevy-pics dot com domain and run the following code:

```
scraper2 = Mechanize.new

scraper2.get("http://www.chevy-pics.com/test.html")

puts scraper2.page.search("#headerBodyType")
```

I get this as output, as expected:

```
<div id="headerBodyType"> SEDAN 4 DR </div>
```

Comment: Sample code would help greatly.

Comment: First, Nokogiri is only doing what you tell it to do, unless you've stumbled on a bug, which is highly unlikely. Second, without your code we can't help you. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance." Strip the HTML you're parsing to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this by changing the line endings on the file in by editor to Mac OS 9, which uses a single [`\r` (carriage return)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character. When you use `puts` on the resulting string the console returns to the start of the line each time this character is seen, but doesn’t start a new line. Each line therefore overwrites what was there before and you end up with the corrupted output you are seeing.

You should be able to tell if this is the case by using [`p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) instead of `puts`. You should see something like `"<div id=\"headerBodyType\">\r  SEDAN 4 DR\r  </div>"` as the output. Notice the `\r` characters used as newlines.

The actual result you get from the query is correct, it’s just displaying that is causing the problems. The solution is probably just to use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) on the text to convert `\r` to the more normal `\n`. I don’t know the best place to do this, it might be possible to change the entire document before Mechanize hands it over to Nokogiri for parsing but I don’t know how you’d do that.

You may need to just change any results you get, as a start try:

```
puts scraper.page.search("#headerBodyType").to_s.gsub("\r", "\n")
```

Comment: Looking at the actual site, they seem to be using `\r\n` (i.e. Windows) newlines, but I can’t check the actual page causing the problem as it’s behind a password. So maybe just that page is using `\r` for some reason, or Mechanize is doing something, or it’s something else altogether.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling this somehow had to do with the way it was formatted, but I was getting nowhere. I will try this out now.

Comment: This method worked perfectly. Thanks! I know Nokogiri really well now, but I am pretty ignorant on text formatting and encoding, so I probably never would have figured this out.